# jQuery - On click add up values of textboxes and show total in a text box

Tags: jquery

Okay so I have a group of values that I want to add together called 'assets' which I minus the total value of 'deductions' to get the total value.

When I click 'Calculate', nothing is happening unless I press F5 in firefox and then press calculate again (and then it somehow works?)

Any ideas on why this is not working correctly?

Here's the page:-

http://everday.co.uk/donate/calculator/

and code:-

```
 <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    /***** NISAB VALUE ******/
    jQuery('#txt-nisab').val('447');
    /************************/
    var assets = parseInt(jQuery('#txt-gold').val()) + parseInt(jQuery('#txt-silver').val()) + parseInt(jQuery('#txt-bank').val()) + parseInt(jQuery('#txt-future').val()) + parseInt(jQuery('#txt-loans').val()) + parseInt(jQuery('#txt-shares').val()) +  parseInt(jQuery('#txt-stock').val());
    var deduct = parseInt(jQuery('#txt-nisab').val()) + parseInt(jQuery('#txt-wages').val()) + parseInt(jQuery('#txt-taxes').val()) + parseInt(jQuery('#txt-borrow').val());
    var zakat = assets - deduct;
    jQuery('#btn-calc').bind('click', function() {
    if(zakat < 0){ zakat = 0 }
    jQuery('#txt-total').val(zakat);
    jQuery('#donation-calulate').show();
    });
    jQuery('#btn-reset').bind('click', function() {
    jQuery('#txt-gold,#txt-silver,#txt-bank,#txt-future,#txt-loans,#txt-shares,#txt-stock,#txt-taxes,#txt-borrow,#txt-wages').val('0');
    jQuery('#donation-calulate').hide();
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L9Y7D/1/) similar to yours that you might use for comparison.

Are you getting any error messages?

You should add the radix to the parseInt - parseInt( var1, 10);

JS

```
var asset1, asset2, asset3, deduction1, deduction2, deduction3, result;

$('#calculate').on('click', function (){
  asset1 = parseInt( $('#a1').val(), 10 );
    if(asset1.length < 1)
    {
     asset1 = 0;
     }
  asset2 = parseInt( $('#a2').val(), 10 );
    if(asset2.length < 1)
    {
     asset2 = 0;
     }
  asset3 = parseInt( $('#a3').val(), 10 );
    if(asset3.length < 1)
    {
     asset3 = 0;
     }
  deduction1 = parseInt( $('#d1').val(), 10 );
    if(deduction1.length < 1)
    {
     deduction1 = 0;
     }
  deduction2 = parseInt( $('#d2').val(), 10 );
    if(deduction2.length < 1)
    {
     deduction2 = 0;
     }
  deduction3 = parseInt( $('#d3').val(), 10 );
    if(deduction3.length < 1)
    {
     deduction3 = 0;
     }
 result2 = (asset1 + asset2 + asset3) - (deduction1 + deduction2 + deduction3);
    console.log(result2);
    $('.result').text("Suggested Donation: " + result2.toFixed(0));
});
```